# JS ругается, на дуструктуризацию

Tags: javascript

JS ругается, что profile уже обьявлена пееменная, но нижняя запись - это деструктиризация кода. почему он ругается?

```js
const profile = {
    name: 'jackques Gluke',
    tag: 'jgluke',
    location: 'Ocho Rios, Jamaica',
    avatar: 'https://www.yandex.ua/',
    stats: {
        followers: 5625,
        views: 4975,
        likes: 1308,
    },
};

const { name, tag, location, avatar } = profile;

console.log(name, tag);
```

Answer (score 2):

Переменная `location` уже существует в глобальном объекте `window`.

> Свойство только для чтения Window.location возвращает объект Location с информацией о текущем расположении документа.
> Источник: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Назовите свою переменную как-то по-другому.

```js
const profile = { name: 'jackques Gluke', tag: 'jgluke', profileLocation: 'Ocho Rios, Jamaica', avatar: 'https://www.yandex.ua/', stats: { followers: 5625, views: 4975, likes: 1308, }, };

const { name, tag, profileLocation, avatar } = profile;

console.log(name, tag, profileLocation);
```

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю глобальный объект

Comment: переменная `name` тоже существует в глобальном объекте, но на нее не ругается :)

Comment: @Grundy Не уверен, но отличие наверное в том, что `name` не `readonly`. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: не, там дело не в readonly явно.